# The sequence $(x_n)$ is given recursively by $x_{0}=0$, $x_{1}=1$, $ x_{n+1}=x_{n} \sqrt{x^{2}_{n-1}+1}+x_{n-1}\sqrt {x^{2}_{n}+1} , \ \ \ n \geq 1 $

Tags: sequences-and-series, recursion, trigonometric-series

The sequence $(x_n)$ is given recursively by $x_{0}=0$, $x_{1}=1$, $$ x_{n+1}=x_{n} \sqrt{x^{2}_{n-1}+1}+x_{n-1}\sqrt {x^{2}_{n}+1} , \ \ \ n \geq 1$$ Find $x_{n}$

I attempted to do a substitution for $x_{n-1}=\tan(u)$ and $x_{n} =\tan(v)$ and I obtained $$x_{n+1}=\frac{sin(v)+ sin(u)}{cos(v)cos(u)}$$.

This is what I have done so far. Would someone help me out with that. Thank you !

Comment: What is supposed to be done with this sequence?

Comment: Find $x_{n}$. Sorry !

Comment: Set $x_n = \sinh{u_n}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By setting $x_n=\sinh u_n$ as suggested by Ron Gordon, we get
$$ \sinh u_{n+1} = \sinh u_n \cosh u_{n-1} + \sinh u_{n-1}\cosh u_n = \sinh(u_n+u_{n-1}) \tag{1}$$
from which $u_{n+1}=u_n+u_{n-1}$ follows from the injectivity of the $\sinh $ function.
Since $u_0=0$ and $u_1=\log(1+\sqrt{2})$, we have
$$ u_n = F_n\cdot\log(\sqrt{2}+1) \tag{2}$$
$$ x_n = \color{red}{\frac{1}{2}\left[(\sqrt{2}+1)^{F_n}-(\sqrt{2}-1)^{F_n}\right]}\tag{3}$$
where $F_n$ is the $n$-th [Fibonacci number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number).

Comment: would you explain how did you come up with $u_{1}$ to be equal $log(1+\sqrt{2})$ and what $F_{n}$ detonated for .

Comment: @ADAM: to solve $\sinh(u_0)=1$ is the same s solving $e^{u_0}-e^{-u_0}=2$, or, by setting $e^{u_0}=v$, the same as solving $v-\frac{1}{v}=2$ with the constraint $v>0$.

Comment: Once you get $(2)$, you have $$\sinh u_n = \frac{1}{2}\left(\exp(F_n \log(\sqrt{2}+1))-\exp\left(F_n\log(\sqrt{2}-1))\right)\right)=\ldots $$

Comment: $F_n$ stands for the $n$-th Fibonacci number, i.e. $$F_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left[\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n\right].$$

Comment: how did you decide to use the n-th Fibonacci number here? I don't see how you made this jump. Thanks!

Comment: @ADAM: Isn't the recursion $$u_{n+2}=u_{n+1}+u_n $$ [quite familiar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)?